# How could I get data from a server in real time?

Tags: json, swift, database, server, swiftui

I am making a messaging app with SwiftUI for the apple watch but I need to get the data off the messages in real time so they get updated every second. Does someone know how to get the messages from the server in realtime?

Thanks

Comment: check server like Firebase and Amazon...they can do this...

Comment: @Chris the server is not the problem, but getting the data in real time in the app so the data is up to date with the server.

Comment: As @Chris said, check Firebase: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database

Comment: A tailor made server solution perhaps if you need data to be pushed in real time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something simple like Firebase (Realtime Database). You will need to create a model for your messageData and an observer for your message, please check https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

If you need further help don't hesitate to message me so I can share a few snippets with you